# laravel 4 - pull similar data in multiple controllers into many views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have users routes like that:

user/13/posts/10
user/13/videos/443
user/13/items/4002

And i want to pull all the data related to 'user/13' every time posts/videos/items views are loaded.
i am also loading the sidebar @include('inc/blog-sidebar') and this file contain data that is the same in all the views and related to 'user/13'.

what is the best way to pull all this information without doing it per function within every controller?

I have tried view:composer within the routes.php (which is bad) and i could not get the user id and get the relevant information.

```
View::composer('posts.show', function($view)
{
    $author = User::find(1);
    $view->with('author',$author);
});
```

also, if this is the best solution then where should i store my view composer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To automatically populate views with data using view composers:

At first create a route pattern for any `URI` like `user/13` or `user/15` like this (In `routes.php` file):

```
// Composers will be used only for this url pattern, i.e. "user/13" or "user/15"
Route::when('user/*', 'prepareView');
```

Then create the `prepareView` filter like this:

```
Route::filter('prepareView', function($route, $request) {

    // Register your three view composers
    View::composers(array(
        // Call the "postsViewComposer" method from
        // ViewComposers for "posts.show" view
        'ViewComposers@postsViewComposer' => 'posts.show',

        // Call the "videsViewComposer" method from
        // ViewComposers for "videos.show" view
        'ViewComposers@videsViewComposer' => 'videos.show',

        // Call the "itemsViewComposer" method from
        // ViewComposers for "items.show" view
        'ViewComposers@itemsViewComposer' => 'items.show',
    ));

});
```

Then create the `ViewComposers` class in `app/viewcomposers` folder:

```
class ViewComposers {

    public function postsViewComposer($view)
    {
         // Get user id, for example, 15
        $id = Route::current()->parameter('id');

        // Then use it to retrieve the model   
        $author = User::find($id);
        return $view->with('author', $author);
    }

    public function videsViewComposer($view)
    {
        // Logic for this view composer
    }

    public function itemsViewComposer($view)
    {
        // Logic for this view composer
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to add your new `class` in your `composer.json` file in `autoload->classmap` like:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        // ...
        "app/viewcomposers"
]
```

At last, just run the `composer dump-autoload` from your `command prompt/terminal` from within your project's root directory. That's it. Now whenever a `URI` for any user with any `id` will be requested, those `view composers` will run to prepare the views.

Comment: Thanks! but for some reason it seems like the viewComposers.php doesn't autoload (even tho i add him to the class map + run dump-autoload. P.S. i work on local server (WAMP). i tried to write "dd('test);" to see if the file autoload but i don't get anything

Comment: Did you added the entry in `classmap` and also did you run `composer dump-autoload` from command prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about eager loading.
You can approach this way,

```
User::with('posts','videos')->get();
```

See, [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: so ill have to do it for each one of my methods over and over again? even though this data is the same and nested within the same route? (user)

Comment: You can have an UserRepository class, write a function like getAllItems() in it which contains this eager loading code, then call it on its instance from inside your controller.