# Different background images when using the same Laravel Layout

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have one layout for my laravel application. I have four views that extend this layout. However, I want a different background image for every view.

My Layout.blade.php file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" />
</head>
<nav>
<!-- NAV STUFF HERE -->
</nav>
<body>

<div class="container">

    @yield('content')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I styled my body in the style.css file like so:

```
body{

background-image: url('/images/image.png');
background-size: cover;
}
```

This styling technique self-evidently gives each view the same background image, which I don't want. I want to be able to set a different background image for each view.

So how do I set each page to have a different background image but still keeping the functionality of them extending a common layout? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of styling the `body` like this:

```
body{
    background-image: url('/images/image.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Apply style to your `view`'s parent element, something like this:

```
.view_parent_image1{
    background-image: url('/images/image1.png');
    background-size: cover;
}

.view_parent_image2{
    background-image: url('/images/image2.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
// View 1
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div class='view_parent_image1'>

    </div>
@stop
```

In another view use the class `view_parent_image2` instead and so on:

```
    // View 2
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div class='view_parent_image2'>

    </div>
@stop
```

**Update:** Another way to do this:

```
// In your master layout
<body class='{{ $bodyClass or "default" }}'>
```

When loading view:

```
return View::make('viewname')->with('bodyClass', 'imageOne');
```

**CSS:**

```
.default { ... }
.imageOne { ... }
```

You can also share a global variable from the `BaseController`:

```
View::share('bodyClass', 'imageOne');
```

**Finally** (maybe best) you can create view composers to automatically set the `class` for a view:

```
View::composers(array(
    'ViewComposers@homeViewComposer' => 'home.index',
    'ViewComposers@aboutViewComposer' => 'about.index',
));

class ViewComposers {
    public function homeViewComposer($view)
    {
        return $view->with('bodyClass', 'homeViewClass');
    }

    public function aboutViewComposer($view)
    {
        return $view->with('bodyClass', 'aboutViewClass');
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.homeViewClass { ... }
.aboutViewClass{ ... }
```

If you need details about how to create and where to place `view composers` then you may [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968279/laravel-4-pull-similar-data-in-multiple-controllers-into-many-views/23975621#23975621).

Comment: This works well, except the background image is still stuck in my container that I defined on the main layout file. Therefore the background doesn't fill up the whole screen. I also tried @yielding a section just for backgrounds, above the container. That didn't seem to work either. Should I just define the container in each individual view?

Comment: You can also pass a `css class/id` with view to the layout and use that class in the `body` and each class could carry a different `background image`.

Comment: You can also share a global variable accross all the views and use that `var` to carry a `css class` name.